# How to get the Coordinates of a view using Rect?

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition, gestures

Referring to the image posted below, Can any one tell me what does it mean that `rect.letf = 0` and `rect.top = 0` while the other methods of the object `rect` shows values? how to get the coordinates of the `topLeft` `topRight` `BottomLeft` `BottomRight` using `rect`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those coordinates are correct. Top and Left on a Rect are relative to containing ViewGroup. A view that sits on the top left corner of a ViewGroup will always have 0 as the Rect.top and Rect.Left since the top left corner of a View is coordinate 0,0.

If you want the coordinates relative to the main Activity or the screen use `View.getLocationInWindow()` or `View.getLocationOnScreen()` respectively.

Comment: which top and left? the top has two corners(left and right) and the bottom as well! sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Rect.top is the Y coordinate of upper bound of the view. Rect.left is the X coordinate of the leftmost bound of the view. In other words, the coordinate defined as (Rec.left, Rect.top) is actually the (x,y) of the top-left corner of the view. Ignoring some special circumstances, this will mostly be (0,0) for a view that's in the top-left corner of it's ViewGroup, as this is relative to the ViewGroup, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: so rect.left, rect.top are the (x,y)coordinates of the top left corner. and rect.right, rect.bottom are the (x,y) coordinates of the bottom right corner. is that right?

Comment: Yes. This is true for any Rect object.